# Php curl doesn't submit form

Tags: php

I want to make a php script that submits a form using curl.
I've seen the other questions regarding this, and tryed like on other answers but i get the same result

I have a simple form that echo the value submited

```
<form action="form.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?PHP
if (! empty($_GET['name'])){
   echo 'Hello, ' . $_GET['name'];
}
?>
```

and here is the curl script

```
$ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.mydom.com/form.php"); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
  'name' => 'Aname',
  'submit' => 'submit'
  ));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  echo "$result";
```

The echoed result is just the form without the "hello  & submitted value"

Comment: Your `curl` is using POST, but your form is expecting GET

Comment: Everything seems to be fine, except the one that everyone has pointed. Try $_POST instead of $_GET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't this be because of this line

```
if (! empty($_GET['name'])){
   echo 'Hello, ' . $_GET['name'];
}
```

you are sending a POST request to the page but you are looking for GET data.

EDIT
Got beaten to the answer >.<